# Subtracting tuples

Tags: python

What is an elegant way of doing the following in python:

```
modes = (1,2,4,5,7,8,9)

start_modes = (1,2,5)
stop_modes = tuple(set(modes) - set(start_modes))

fast_modes = (2,7)
slow_modes = tuple(set(modes) - set(fast_modes))
```

I'm defining the behaviour of a system I'm testing. In my tests I will sometimes be interested in iterating over all `modes` and sometimes I will be interested in iterating over `slow_mode`s for example.

I want all variables defined above to be immutable since they should never change. I would also prefer if their order was always the same since I would like my tests to behave consistently.

Comment: Please tell us the result you want to achieve

Comment: @Jesuisme Question updated

Comment: An example of the desired output please; like (1,2,4) - (1,2) = (4,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use [*sets*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) instead:

```
modes = frozenset([1,2,4,5,7,8,9])

start_modes = {1,2,5}
stop_modes = modes - start_modes

fast_modes = {2,7}
slow_modes = modes - fast_modes
```

Here `frozenset()` is the `set()` equivalent of `tuple()`; an immutable type. The `start_modes` and `fast_modes` sets use the `{...}` set literal notation, producing a mutable `set()` object instead. You can always use `frozenset()` for those as well.

Sets can only contain unique elements and do not maintain an order for the elements. You can still convert a set back to a tuple, but a tuple seems like the wrong data type for your problem.

Sets are iterable; you can loop over these, but the order depends on the insertion and deletion history of the set and on the values contained.

If order *is* important, use a generator expression in a `tuple()` call to produce your values:

```
modes = (1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9)

start_modes = (1, 2, 5)
stop_modes = tuple(m for m in modes if m not in start_modes)

fast_modes = (2, 7)
slow_modes = tuple(m for m in modes if m not in fast_modes)
```

Although it doesn't make much difference here, if you can make `start_modes` and `fast_modes` `set` or `frozenset` objects the `not in` negative membership tests will be faster.

Comment: I want modes to be immutable

Comment: @chepner: I need more tea, obviously. Corrected.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I am testing a system and in certain tests I test all modes and in others I test for example slow_modes. I would prefer if the different mode list are of a fixed order since it feels more consistent for a test it modes in the same order every time. I've update me question with this info.

Answer (score 1):

Use a set:

```
modes = {1,2,4,5,7,8,9}
stop_modes = modes - {1,2,5}
```

Comment: I want modes to be immutable

Comment: @Baz: then you can use a `frozenset` instead.